# CSS Infinite animation iteration delay

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can I set up the animation, so it has no delay between iterations?

For example I have this code:

```
.square{
   margin:0 auto 0 auto;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   border:2px solid #FFF;   

    perspective:1000;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    animation:spin 3s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin{
    0%{
       transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    50%{
       transform: rotateY(180deg);
    } 
    100%{
       transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
}
```

If you check out this code, you will see that it has a second or a fraction of a second delay between the iterations of the animation.

How can I take it out so that it looks like it`s running smoothly and continuously?

Comment: can you share your html??

Comment: @noob Html is basic, does not have anything in the body except the square div "<div class="romb"></div>"

Comment: I don't have problems with the animation (Firefox), You can take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change. Here can you see a http://jsfiddle.net/4nypv4ux/. I know I don't have the right html code because you are using perspective.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j0gq5wmy/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me once I add the appropriate browser prefixes - http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/uar7zvyv/